# Get user console input before user hitting enter

Tags: python

I have a quite simple problem.

I want to get some console input from a user (without an enter press at the end) and do something with it right away.

I quickly saw that the `input()` function from python would not work. I thought maybe you could write something like this:

```py
sys.stdout.write("Input: ")

while True:
    line = sys.stout.readline()
    // Do something with the lines
```

But unfortunately it does not work because `stdout` is not readable. With `stdin` it does not work either because it waits for a enter press of the user.

Is it somehow possible to get lines without the user submit it?

Comment: What is the usecase of this? i.e. might it be easier to detect a keypress using another method?

Comment: @FinHARRIS. Shortly the case is that I will have print statements in my application while the user needs to input something. I could not find an answer to print something above a running input, so I thought maybe you could delete the input statement, print the wanted line and then create the input again. This part was no problem (I solved it with threading) but with this method I need to keep track of the current input of the user so it does not disappear.

Answer (score 0):

You can get input from console interactively in byte format instead of getting a string with `input` command.

```
import sys
while True:
   c = sys.stdin.read(1) # Read one byte
```

Comment: This requires enter still.

Comment: @FinHARRIS right.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you might be looking for.

To get this working you will need to use `pip install keyboard` in the command line first.

```py
import keyboard

while True:
    key_pressed = keyboard.read_key()
    print(f'You pressed {key_pressed}.')
```

Comment: I thought of that too and that might be the only solution but that seems not very elegant to me... I will try tho

Comment: Its about as elegant as it gets :)

Comment: Is there really no way to print something before another print statement xD?
Like that for example:
`print("hello")`
`sys.stdout.write("Hola",beforeline=True)`

Or something like that?

Comment: What do you mean exactly? Do can you not just print hello after the other line?

Comment: I know it seems a bit weird. I 2 threads. The first thread is for printing (Does not have to something with the user input). The second one is for the user input. I want to have the input always at the bottom. Simply it's just like a chat in the shell (User input at the bottom and incoming messages appear above the input)

Comment: You basically have to render frames, for each frame, clear the console then print the screen top to bottom. Do you have to do this in the console, a UI will be much easier and have a better UX.

Comment: Okay. You are right. What a waste of time. I will try it with an UI. Thank you. Have a nice weekend